# How to implement an addate utility in perl?

Tags: perl, date, strftime

I have no experience with perl and I need to create an utility which will print a date after adding an offset, the format string is an strftime format string.

> Format: ./adddate number_of_days [format_string]
>
> Example: ./adddate -1 "%a, %b %d" # Print the date for yesterday

Comment: Use [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/) to parse the incoming timestamp and [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) to manipulate it.

Comment: [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) is another alternative.

Comment: so you have date and offset and will get result (date+offset) in specific strftime format?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, (date+offset) in specific strftime format

Answer (score 3):

After some research I was able to write the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use DateTime;
$offset = $ARGV[0];
$format = $ARGV[1];
$dt = DateTime->now();
$dt->add( days => $offset );
print $dt->strftime($format)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To add days, simply increment the `tm_mday` field of the time in broken-down form (as returned by `localtime`). A `mktime`-`localtime` roundtrip will then renormalise it, accounting for month or year rollovers.

```
use strict;
use feature qw( say );
use POSIX qw( mktime strftime );

my $offset = $ARGV[0];
my $format = $ARGV[1];

my @t = localtime;
$t[3] += $offset;  # tm_mday field

say strftime( $format, localtime mktime @t );
```

All core modules.